# Codeigniter 4.4.3 return view from a subdiretory

Tags: view, subdirectory, default-value, codeigniter-4

`* I have my directory like app/modules/auth/view/auth.php
and controller like app/modules/auth/controller/Auth.php *
*so i want to return auth.php from Auth.php but its showing invalid file error all the time . Please help me fix this */

/* I tried
`below is route code` */

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\modules\auth\controller');
$routes->setDefaultController('Auth');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('login');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override('');
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
$routes->get('virtualclassroom', 'Auth::login'); 

<?php

namespace App\modules\auth\controller;


use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException;

class Auth extends Controller
{
    protected $default='modules\views\loginpage';
    public function login()
    {
        return view('auth_login');

    }
}
```

*This is controller . But i want content of login page *